# Add Owin Facebook login to existing application in class library

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, facebook, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a class library that manages different projects that corresponds to MVC applications.

With [this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on) I can make an entire MVC5 website with Facebook login authentication.

But what I want is to integrate this type of authentication (i think its `Owin`) to my class library and that every other MVC project (websites) use this library to perform the authentication.

How can i achieve this? First the Owin integration and then what i need to integrate to what project that i have?

My Solution structure is like this:

```
Solution
   |--->DataModel (MyClassLibrary)
   |--->MVCApplication1
   |--->MVCApplication2
   |--->MVCApplicationX
```

All MVCApplication{something} is using the DataModel, so my DataModel should have the objects needed to login in the different MVCApplication{something} websites.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all your User data to go through your DataModel, you do have a little work cut out for you.  I did this in my last project and it's not that bad, but you do have to do a little work.

**Before you read the rest of this, read this article:** http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/overview-of-custom-storage-providers-for-aspnet-identity

By default, ASP.NET Identity will use its own separate database to hold on to login information, which you don't want (you want it stored in one place in your DataModel).

First, you're going to have to provide your own implementation of `IUserStore`, and use that when you manage authentication in your MVCApplications (usually in the AccountController).

I'd add a new project in your solution called `Authentication`, which should have a class like:

```
public class UserStore : IUserStore<IdentityUser, long>,
                             IUserLoginStore<IdentityUser, long>,
                             IUserPasswordStore<IdentityUser, long>,
                             IUserClaimStore<IdentityUser, long>
```

You'll have to implement all of the methods from the interfaces, which are going to call into your DataModel to get user data or claims data (the Facebook logins are stored as Claims against an IdentityUser).

Here are the classes you'll need in your DataModel:

```
public class IdentityUser : IUser<long>
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string PasswordHash { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ExternalLogin> Logins { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserClaim> Claims { get; set; } 
}

public class ExternalLogin
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string LoginProvider { get; set; }
    public string ProviderKey { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public virtual IdentityUser User { get; set; }
}

public class UserClaim
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public IdentityUser User { get; set; }
}
```

Some notes: I wanted user ids to be longs, so I extended `IUser<long>`.  If you're cool with strings, you can omit the type parameter there and on all the interfaces you implement for your UserStore.

The UserManager is the object that Controllers use to interact with your authentication system.  They talk to UserStores, which you provided a custom implementation of.  UserStores talk to a DataStore, which in your case, will be your DataModel.

Here's a snippet of what your AccountController might look like to use your custom UserStore.  All you have to do is construct one and pass it to the UserManager's constructor.

```
public UserManager<IdentityUser, long> UserManager { get; private set; }

public AccountController()
{
    IUserStore<IdentityUser, long> userStore = new UserStore();
    UserManager = new UserManager<IdentityUser, long>(store);
}
```

Comment: This is kind what i want but in my new Authentication project.. what nuget packages will i have to add?

Comment: The new Authentication project should only reference this NuGet package: Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core

Comment: Also, you should remove references to Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework, because you're providing your own implementation now (through your Data Model)

Comment: Yes, my webapplication stores the users using AspNet authentication (with mysql connector).

Comment: Does this answer your question?

Comment: I'm investigating a little bit more and testing your code